# Frame inside custom view

Tags: java, view, graphics, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have implemented a custom view in my Eclipse plugin project, where I want to display different graphs, which are selected by the user. I have no problem with creating a custom view, using `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC` and drawing the required parts but I would like to implement the following:

Inside the custom view I want to have some fixed area on the bounds of the view, where I can display the coordinate system (x- and y-axis with the corresponding labeling), which is fixed. Between these bounds I would like to display the graph, which is changing dynamically, depending on user selection.

So what I need is a custom view, that is built like the following:

[image: Mockup]

Inside the grey area on the left and on the bottom I want to have the coordinate system axes (shown red) and inside the white area I want to draw the graph.

How do I create such an area inside my view? It should just be a filed, without any translations or scales, just a independend area, like a view inside a view...

```
@Override
public void init(IViewSite site) throws PartInitException {
    super.init(site);
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            drawCoordinateSystem(e);
            drawGraph(e);
    });

public void drawCoordinateSystem(PaintEvent e) {
    // 1. create area inside view
    // 2. draw coordinate system
}

public void drawGraph() {
    // 3. draw graph
}
```

I know how to solve point 2 and 3. But I don't know, how to create such an area inside my view.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could You specify what You want to achieve? You have problem with drawing? Graph area will be translated (scrolled horizontally and vertically) and/or scaled?

Comment: @Kuba It should just be a filed, without any translations or scales, just a independend area, like a view inside a view

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add multiple controls and handle drawing for different cases in a different way.

For example, instead of having just one monolithic Canvas that draws everything from graph to coordinates, to helpful labels. Add a bunch of label controls on top for showing coordinates, add a parent, or labels for coordinate systems etc.

Your `createPartControl` should look something like below:

```java
    Composite topBar = new Composite(parent, SWT.None);
    topBar.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    Label title = new Label(topBar, SWT.NONE);
    title.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false));

    Label x = new Label(topBar, SWT.NONE);
    Label y = new Label(topBar, SWT.NONE);

    Composite graphArea = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    graphArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Canvas xAxis = new Canvas(graphArea, SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.CENTER, GridData.FILL, false, true);
    gd.widthHint = 10;
    xAxis.setLayoutData(gd);
    xAxis.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            drawXAxis();
        }
    });

    Canvas graph = new Canvas(graphArea, SWT.NONE);
    graph.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            drawGraph(e);
        }
    });

    Label emptySpace = new Label(graphArea, SWT.NONE);

    Canvas yAxis = new Canvas(graphArea, SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false);
    gd.heightHint = 10;
    xAxis.setLayoutData(gd);
    yAxis.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            drawYAxis();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should draw everything in Your paintListener, if Your graph changes just redraw area of graph for example:

```
Rectangle rect = getGraphBoundries(); //you must implement this method
canvas.redraw(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, true);
```

this will redraw graph area. To avoid unnecessary computing of axes area in in paintListener paintEvent's gc has area that need to be redrawn called clipping. You can write condition like this:

```
public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
...
   if(drawGraph(e.gc.getClipping().intersects(getGraphBoundries())) {
       drawGraph(e);
   }
...
}
```

Comment: The drawing of the graph inside the paint listener and redrawing new graphs is not the problem. I can't use clipping, to draw the axes because I don't want to just cut the the graph, but I want to draw it directly next to the axes.

Comment: Seriously I don't understand your problem. Just draw axes' background and axes after drawing graph. Axes will cover left and bottom area and it will look like different view. You can even add another paint listener for this to get more separation in your code, but remember to add it AFTER paint listener drawing graph.